# How to add unique words and their number of occurrences in a List

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

I am trying to write a program in C# that will read text from a file and will count the number of times each unique word shows up and also keeps track of what words are in the file. For example, in the string "this is my text and this is it" I would get:

this - 2
is - 2
my - 1
text - 1
and - 1
it - 1

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I am new to C# and I have not seen too many things that I fully understand from searching for this.

Edit:

So here is the code that I have tried. It seems that my list that is returned just has the last word in the file over and over and the count is off. Also even though I try to get rid of capitals and periods, they still show up.

```
public override List<WordEntry> GetWordCount()
{
        List<WordEntry> words = new List<WordEntry>();
        WordEntry wordEntry = new WordEntry();
        string[] tokens = null;
        string line, temp;
        int count = 0, index = 0;

        while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            temp = Regex.Replace(line, @"\([0-9].\)", "");
            temp.ToLower();
            tokens = temp.Split(null);

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
            {
                wordEntry.Word = tokens[i];
                foreach (var word in tokens)
                {
                    if (word == tokens[i])
                        count++;
                }//end foreach
                wordEntry.WordCount = count;
                words.Add(wordEntry);
            }//end for
        }//end while

        return words;
}//end GetWordCount
```

Comment: Yes but nobody here will do it for you. Come up with an attempt and people here can help you.

Comment: Look into `string.Contains`, possibly `string.Remove`, `Dictionary` and Algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first step is to look up StreamReader class...the StreamReader class will be used to read the text file...then split each line of the text file into a String[]...after you have gotten this far ..you can loop thru the String[] with a foreach loop and count the number of time a word is in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grouping, just split your template and group by word:

```
var template = "this is my text and this is it";
var result = template.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     .GroupBy(grp => grp)
     .Select(grp => new {Word = grp.Key , Count= grp.Count()})
     .ToList();
```